# Matlab grouping the same data values together in livescript?

Tags: matlab, grouping

I have set of data in csv format which I imported in matlab as live script (Sales_Data) having the following sort of information in it,

```
Day         Sales

Monday          5
Tuesday         12
Monday          4
Thursday        7
Saturday        2
Wednesday       3
Friday          0
Thursday        19  
Saturday        NaN
Friday          6
```

The above example is just for an idea otherwise the data is too large to calculate the required info by hand.

I intend to calculate which day of the week had the most number of sales? Keeping in mind that within the data the particular number of day has occured more than once with different sales value.

The final resultant table should be after adding all of the values of a particular day in a table and listing it like following;

```
Day         Sales

Monday          9
Tuesday         12
Wednesday       3
Thursday        26
Friday          6
Saturday        2
```

Within the live script I added the code as following but I am getting the day entries multiple times.

```
TotalSales = groupsummary(Sales_Data,{'Day','Sales'})
```

Any suggestion on getting the result as needed and also how to group all the same Day data along with their Sales value together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for this:

```
% These lines are only to import your data
days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Mon", "Thu", "Sat", "Wed", "Fri", "Thu", "Sat", "Fri"]';
sales = [5,12,4,7,2,3,0,19, NaN, 6]';
T = table(days, sales);

% This prvides the sum of sales all days
groupsummary(T, 'days', 'sum', 'sales')
```

Result:

```
ans =

  6×3 table

    days     GroupCount    sum_sales
    _____    __________    _________

    "Fri"        2             6    
    "Mon"        2             9    
    "Sat"        2             2    
    "Thu"        2            26    
    "Tue"        1            12    
    "Wed"        1             3
```

This is explained in the [docs of groupsummary](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.groupsummary.html).